# Javascript - using different parts of chained functions, by conditions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

generally in Javascript, say I have got this code:

```
return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/company`, data).then(companyResponse => {

    }).catch(error => {
        throw (error);
    });
};
```

Now, in some cases I want to call the "post" method with some parameters (as written above) and in other cases I'd like to use "put" with different params.
Something like this:

```
// Pseudo code
if(some condition){
    // use this: axios.put(`${ROOT_URL}/company`, data, config)
}
    // use this: axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/company`, data)
}
```

What is the best practice for doing that?

Comment: You should drop the useless `.catch(error => { throw error; })`

Comment: Don't you just need a function that you can pass various options into and the function then looks at those options to decide what type of request to send and with what parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Something like this

Yes, exactly like this. Remember that promises are just values, you can pass them around and store them in variables or make them the results of expressions.

```
return (dispatch) => {
    var promise;
    if (some condition)
        promise = axios.put(`${ROOT_URL}/company`, data, config);
    else
        promise = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/company`, data)
    return promise.then(companyResponse => {
        …
    });
}
```

Or use the conditional operator:

```
return (dispatch) => {
    return (some condition
      ? axios.put(`${ROOT_URL}/company`, data, config);
      : axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/company`, data)
    ).then(companyResponse => {
        …
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bracket notation with the ternary operator to use post or put depending on condition. You can also use the ternary operator to pass the config if the condition is met, and otherwise pass an empty object as config.

```
axios[condition ? 'put' : 'post'](`${ROOT_URL}/company`, data, condition ? config : {})
```

Comment: Didn't know about this option of bracket notation with ternary. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This was my first thought too

Answer (score 0):

You can also use axios config object to specify method:

```
const method = condition ? 'put' : 'post' // ternary operator
axios({ method, url: `${ROOT_URL}/company`, data })
  .then(...)
  .catch(...)
```